# Braintree dropin ui showing junk characters insted of bullet mark in card number

Tags: node.js, braintree

Well, I am not able to find the answer anywhere for this.

So i am creating a `client token` with `customer id` to show already used payment methods in dropin ui. But instead of showing the card numbers like this
[image]

its showing me like this.

[image]

Anyone facing this issue? Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Drop-in UI is trying to render the dots in the credit card number placeholder, but the page isn't accepting UTF-8 characters. This problem should be resolved if you add `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your `<head>` tag.

Alternatively, you can include the UTF-8 charset in your [Drop-in UI script tag](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/setup-and-integration/javascript/v3#setup). As an example, it would look something like this:

```
<script charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.12.0/js/dropin.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well your comment is a good practice to implement in html. But issue was the bad js file format that i have saved in my package. So updating a dropin ui js solved the issue.